# Convert NSRange in Objective-C to Swift

Tags: swift, nsrange

How do I convert this to Swift:

```
NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Apple_HFS "];
NSRange range = [tempString rangeOfString:searchString];
NSUInteger *idx = range.location + range.length;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `String`, you can just reference `endIndex`:

```
let searchString: String = "Apple_HFS "
if let range: Range<String.Index> = tempString.rangeOfString(searchString) {
    let index = range.endIndex
    let stringAfter = tempString.substringFromIndex(index)
    // do something with `stringAfter`
} else {
    // not found
}
```

I included the types so you could see what's going on, but generally I'd just write:

```
let searchString = "Apple_HFS "
if let range = tempString.rangeOfString(searchString) {
    let stringAfter = tempString.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
    // do something with `stringAfter`
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
var str : NSString = "A string that include the searched string Apple_HFS inside"

let searchString : NSString = "Apple_HFS "
let range : NSRange = str.rangeOfString(searchString) // (42, 10)
let idx : Int = range.location + range.length // 52
```

Demonstration : http://swiftstub.com/831969865/

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution **without using ANY objc methods or types:**

Suppose you have:

```
let nsrange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 5)
let string = "My string"
```

And now you need to convert `NSRange` to `Range`:

```
let range = Range(start: advance(string.startIndex, nsrange.location), end: advance(string.startIndex, nsrange.location + nsrange.length))
```

Comment: Don't use this code. It will not work with composed characters or emojis. Ranges in Objective-C represent UTF-16 code units. Ranges in Swift represent extended grapheme clusters. If you don't understand what I am talking about, read the Swift documentation about Strings.